# Can't use the local object detection scenario in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ml.net

I'm using ml.net to do object detection with my own data set. To label the images I used VOTT to label them and export them. Unfortunately there is no way to train my VOTT export locally.

Because I'm very new to this topic my question is, is there a way to train a model with my export of VOTT to detect these objects?

Comment: Does this tutorial help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-model-builder

Comment: That is the one i'm following but there they use azure to train the model. Because I don't have a subscription I can't use azure. But thanks anyway